# Sorting a nsdictionary, how does it work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm having some trouble understanding the logic behind this `compare-using-selector` thing.

I have the following code, I'm trying extract the Keys and sorting them at the same time. But, it does not sort.  The output NSArray's order never changes no matter what I do.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictToSort = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Joe", [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"mark", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"mdark", [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], nil];

NSArray *dictToSortKeys = [dictToSort keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

NSLog(@"Not Sorted" );

NSNumber *xx = dictToSortKeys[0];
NSNumber *xy = dictToSortKeys[1];
NSNumber *xz = dictToSortKeys[2];
NSLog(@"Sorted %d %d %d", xx.integerValue , xy.integerValue, xz.integerValue);
```

I don't get how this `compare:` function work. It says it returns `NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedSame or NSOrderedDescending`, but there is not way to receive these returns.  And also, this is supposed to work magically?  The documentation is quite poor for this comparison thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are confused about what `keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:` does.  It sorts the dictionary entries by **value**, and returns the keys in that order.

Your dictionary contains these entries:

```
Key Value
--- -----
 1  mark
 2  Joe
 3  mdark
```

The `keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:` method effectively sorts that table by the “Value” column:

```
Key Value
--- -----
 2  Joe
 1  mark
 3  mdark
```

(Note that `Joe` is alphabetically before `mark` and `mark` is alphabetically before `mdark`.)

Then it returns an array of the keys, in the order just computed: `@[ @2, @1, @3 ]`.

Note that `keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:` never compares the keys.  It **only** compares the values.

If you want to sort the key array by the keys themselves, just do this:

```
NSArray *dictToSortKeys = [dictToSort.allKeys
    sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: But how would I reverse the order? Edit: right I'd use the conpare:option.