# Match NSDictionary Key Value Pairs

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, loops

I have the following NSDictionary with the following data structure:

```
Food Count (values) - Food Name (key)
```

I sort that NSDictionary's food count like so:

```
    NSArray *sortedFood = [[detailDictionary allValues] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([obj1 intValue] < [obj2 intValue])
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    if ([obj1 intValue] > [obj2 intValue])
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

It has sorted it the following way

```
100
98
50
30
etc.
```

I am trying to use that new sortedFood array to then only show the top 5 value, key pairs for the food.

For example, if Apple's is the name of the food that has the value of 100, it would appear first.

So far I have the loop, but nothing else.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
}
```

Not sure what else to do. I think this is more difficult because the whole dictionary isn't sorted in the same way as the new array, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I think the answer on this question will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257582/sorting-a-nsdictionary-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try
`-[keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:]` in `NSDictionary`, it is sorted by value and get the key results.